# When textInput is focused flatlist scrolls smoothly when unfocused from textInput flatlist starts lagging

Tags: android, reactjs, scrollview, flatlist

So basically I want to use horizontal flatlist for selected image rendering not added logic yet but i took dummy json for the purpose,  inside scrollView I'm making form using react native but problem is that while scrolling flatlist items it is not scrolling smoothly, but whenever I click on textInput the flatlist starts scrolling smoothly wihtout any proplem as textInput gets unfocused the flatlist again starts to lagg please help me or suggest me some solutions

```
const dummyImages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: require('../../assets/images/approve.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: require('../../assets/images/guestProfilef.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: require('../../assets/images/img.jpg'),
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: require('../../assets/images/sam.jpg'),
  },
];

const PopulatedImageSection = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.populatedImageWrapper}>
      <FlatList
        data={dummyImages}
        // snestedScrollEnabled
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ListFooterComponent={() => (
          <DIcon
            name={'pluscircleo'}
            provider={'AntDesign'}
            size={50}
            color={'#353535'}
          />
        )}
        ListFooterComponentStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft: 10}}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={styles.eachPopulatedImageWrapper}>
            <Image source={item.url} style={styles.populatedProductImages} />
          </View>
        )}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const Rooms = () => {
  const [productTypeState, setProductTypeState] = useState(1);
  const [uploadTriggered, setUploadTriggered] = useState(false);

  const [enableScroll, setEnableScroll] = useState(true);

  function productTypeSelectLogic(id) {
    setProductTypeState(id);
  }

  function selectImageHandler() {
    setUploadTriggered(true);
  }

  const ProdutTypeComponent = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        style={[
          styles.eachProductTypeWrapper,
          productTypeState == item.id
            ? styles.eachProductTypeWrapperSelected
            : null,
        ]}
        android_ripple={{color: 'white'}}
        onPress={productTypeSelectLogic.bind(null, item.id)}>
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.eachProductTypeWrapperText,
            productTypeState == item.id
              ? styles.eachProductTypeWrapperTextSelected
              : null,
          ]}>
          {item.type}
        </Text>
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} nestedScrollEnabled>
      <Text style={styles.productTypeTitle}>Select product type</Text>
      <View style={styles.productTypeWrapper}>
        <FlatList
          onScroll={() => setEnableScroll(false)}
          data={productType}
          renderItem={props => <ProdutTypeComponent {...props} />}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          scrollEnabled
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} placeholder="Product title" />
        <TextInput
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={5}
          placeholder={"Product's short description"}
          style={[styles.inputText, {textAlignVertical: 'top'}]}
        />
        <Pressable
          style={styles.selectImageWrapper}
          onPress={selectImageHandler}>
          {uploadTriggered ? (
            <PopulatedImageSection />
          ) : (
            <View style={styles.selectImageContainer}>
              <DIcon
                name={'ios-cloud-upload'}
                provider={'Ionicons'}
                size={120}
                color={'#35353590'}
              />
              <Text style={styles.selectImageTitle}>Upload product image</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Rooms;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  productTypeTitle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    paddingHorizontal: 22,
    marginTop: 10,
    color: '#353535',
  },
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 22,
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  productTypeWrapper: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  eachProductTypeWrapper: {
    padding: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#353535',
  },
  eachProductTypeWrapperText: {
    color: '#353535',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  eachProductTypeWrapperSelected: {
    backgroundColor: '#353535',
  },
  eachProductTypeWrapperTextSelected: {
    color: '#fff',
  },

  //!#From Verificaiton
  inputText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#353535',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    marginVertical: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
  },
  selectImageWrapper: {
    borderColor: '#353535',
    height: 170,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  selectImageContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  selectImageTitle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#35353590',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  populatedImageWrapper: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  eachPopulatedImageWrapper: {
    width: 120,
    height: '100%',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#35353550',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  populatedProductImages: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

Comment: I solved the proplem by unwrapping flatlist component from pressable it started functioning properly, but I still don't know how onfocus to textInput it was working back then